# Call method from another form

Tags: ms-access

I have a navigation form with two subforms that looks something like this:

[image]

When the button in Subform A is clicked, I would like to call a method from Subform B. The method is defined like this:

```
Public Sub MyMethod()
    Debug.Print "MyMethod called"
End Sub
```

I tried using `Forms!SubformB.MyMethod` but I get the error `Database cannot find the referenced form 'SubformB'`. Referring to [this](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) page, I also tried `Forms!NavigationForm!SubformB.MyMethod` but then I get `Database cannot find the referenced form 'NavigationForm'`. Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Thank you.

Comment: Disclaimer: It's been YEARS since I did anything in access ... what about `Me!SubformB.MyMethod` ?

Comment: Thanks Lynn, I gave it a shot but I get `Database can't find the field 'SubformB'`. I think that's because the `Me` here is referencing SubformA, which isn't the parent of SubformB.

Comment: You may need a reference to SubformB. Can the Navigation Form pass SubformA a reference to SubformB when it instantiates it? Or can SubformA get a reference back to the Navigation Form?

Comment: @Jura FYI, I think you can reference the parent and then the child via either `Me.Parent!SubFormB`or `Me!Parent!SubFormB`, but I think Gord's answer is still relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure this out but there's a catch - the other form has to be open. This worked for me though so I'm posting the solution here.

First, navigate to the form:

```
DoCmd.BrowseTo ObjectType:=acBrowseToForm, _
ObjectName:="SubformB", _
PathToSubformControl:="NavigationForm.NavigationSubform", _
DataMode:=acFormEdit
```

Then make a pointer to the subform:

```
Dim f As Form_SubformB
Set f = Forms("NavigationForm").NavigationSubform.Form
```

And you are free to call the method:

```
f.MyMethod()
```

Note: you will most likely have to make the method `Public` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

`Function` and `Sub` procedures defined in the class module of a Form are considered to be private to that form. If you want a `Sub` that can be called from several different forms then move that `Sub` to a "regular" VBA Module (i.e., one that is created when you choose `Insert > Module` from the menu bar in the VBA editor) and be sure to declare it as `Public`.

Comment: Gord, I'd like to try this but I'm stuck on something - even if I put the `Sub` in its own module I still need a reference to Subform B for part of the work. My `Forms` collection only contains the master navigation form, and I'm not sure how to extract the subform. I even tried digging through the controls of the navigation form but nothing. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of code I have that toggest the AllowEdits method of a subform when clicking a button on the mainform.  Pretty sure this is what you are after.

```
Function ToggleEditStatus_Child(WhichForm, WhichChild As String)
 'Changes the AllowEdits setting of the SubForm parameter

 Dim Cform As Object

 Set Cform = Forms(WhichForm).Controls(WhichChild).Form
 Cform.AllowEdits = Not Cform.AllowEdits
 Forms(WhichForm).Refresh
 Cform.Refresh
 Forms(WhichForm).Controls(WhichChild).SetFocus
 Set Cform = Nothing

End Function
```